# Issue with System.Text.Json Serialization of Floating Point Numbers in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, floating-point, system.text.json

I'm encountering an issue with System.Text.Json in C# related to the serialization of floating-point numbers. When serializing a float with a decimal part (e.g., 4.0), the library seems to omit the decimal part, resulting in the JSON representation being just 4 instead of 4.0.

I've tried using various configurations, including setting NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals and NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString, but the behavior remains the same.

Is there a way to preserve the complete representation (e.g., 4.0) during serialization, or is there a known limitation with the current version of System.Text.Json?

Thank you for any insights or suggestions.

Comment: But 4.0 is the same as 4, right? Or does 3.1415 get represented as 3?

Comment: This seems like an X-Y question. "4.0" and "4" are programmatically the same, so why do you want to do this?

Comment: @rene , in C#, 4.0 and 4 are considered the same numerically. However, when I serialize data to JSON for transmission to another program, the distinction between 4 (int) and 4.0 (float) becomes important in the receiving program.

To clarify, the value 3.14 is represented as 3.14, maintaining its decimal part.

The issue specifically arises with rounded float values.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the receiving program not deserialising JSON properly.

Comment: This is not an issue, as JSON defines the data type simply "Number", and not Int or Float.   So as long as it is correctly defined in your code as float, then you can be sure that it will be handled correctly.  If you are worried about the receivers of the file, then you need to provide documentation to state what to expect.

Comment: JSON does not have distinguish between float and int, it only has a concept of [number](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-6).

Comment: @MatthewWatson , no, the communication between the two programs is defined by a standard, and the receiving program should differentiate between float and int using the decimal point in the numbers.

Comment: _"and the receiving program should differentiate between float and int using the decimal point in the numbers"_  - TBH this sounds like a very brittle approach.

Comment: So, the standard isn't JSON then ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON does not distinguish between `float` and `int`, it only has a concept of [Number](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-6) so in general you should avoid relying on the particular number formatting.

If currently you can't fix the app which uses the JSON you can use [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0) which will use specific [number format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). For example:

```
class FloatConverter : JsonConverter<float>
{
    public override float Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, float value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // at least one decimal place, add reasonable amount of places with #
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString("0.0########", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var serialize = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new float[] { 1, 1.1f, 4.5555f }, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new FloatConverter() }
});
Console.WriteLine(serialize); // prints "[1.0,1.1,4.5555]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments,

Here's how I fixed the problem:

- Creating a Class :

  ```
  public class AddZerosToFloat : JsonConverter<float>
   {
       public AddZerosToFloat() { }

   public override float Read(
       ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
       Type typeToConvert,
       JsonSerializerOptions options)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
   }
   public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
   {
       return objectType == typeof(float);
   }
   public override void Write(
       Utf8JsonWriter writer,
       float value,
       JsonSerializerOptions options)
   {
       if (Math.Truncate(value) == value)
       {
           writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
       }
       else
       {
           writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));


      }
   }}
  ```
- Add serializer option :

  ```
   string JsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(structClass, new JsonSerializerOptions 
   {
        ... other parameters
       Converters = { new AddZerosToFloat()}
   });
  ```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**